# Boundary Condition for Dirac comb potential in solving independant Schrodinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

The Periodic potential is

[image]

And, the general solution is:

[image]

Then, boundary condition at $x=a$ is:

[image]

Where does $2\Omega u(a)$ comes from?

I know that boundary condition is just

1) $U(x<a)(a)=U(x>a)(a)$ and

2) $U'(x<a)(a)=U'(x>a)(a)$

Comment: What is the context for this? what is the physical problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @BySymmetry at the end, I am trying to obtain energy spectrum i.e. allowed bands etc. of this periodic potential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us integrate the Schrödinger equation:
$$
\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)\right)u(x)=E\, u(x)
$$
from $x=a-\epsilon$ to $x=a+\epsilon$ and take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$.

Individual terms would be:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int\limits^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon}-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} u''(x) \, dx&=&-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}(u'(a+0)-u'(a-0)),\\
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int\limits^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon}V(x)u(x)\,dx&=&\frac{\hbar^2\Omega}{m}u(a),\\
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int\limits^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon} E u(x) \, dx &=&0.
\end{eqnarray}
Adding  them up and dropping common factor we obtain the second boundary condition:
$$
u'(a+0)-u'(a-0)-2\Omega u(a)=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Other sources that I checked, shows exactly the same method. But, they lacked details. You made very clear.

Comment: Also, I was wondering, 1st boundary condition is obtained in this way too ?